# Set your journey to the wellness.. "set" used as "begin" , goes right here?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Using 'set' as 'begin' or closely similar way.

The sentence "Set your journey to the wellness.." is ok?

Set goes right here?

From definition, I want to use "set" for this purpose..
cause (someone or something) to start doing something.
"the incident set me thinking"

Comment: It’s hard to know what you’re actually asking here. “Set your journey to the wellness” as a sentence makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. It needs to be changed in order to make sense, and you would have to tell us _what the sentence is supposed to mean_ in order for us to help you do that. I would also advise you to have a look at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com), our sister site dedicated to those who are learning English, rather than discussing its finer points.

Comment: As john says, I want to use the "set" as "tune". It would make sense with the sentence.. if replace the wellness with aliveness.. "set your journey to the aliveness"

Comment: No, sorry, that is still not a sentence that makes any sense in English. You cannot ‘set’ a journey to anything. ‘Aliveness’ possibly makes even less sense than ‘wellness’. The meaning of ‘set’ that John was talking about here is what the dictionary defines as, “adjust a device (or its controls) so that it performs a particular operation”. It is what you do when you change your _settings_ in a computer program. A journey cannot be ‘set’. It makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Do you mean:  "*Set out on your journey to wellness?*"  I.e., Take the first steps toward your goal of becoming healthy, fit, and active.

Comment: Thanks Jim, yes I mean that.. Thank you Janus for your help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which "wellness" is this? I suspect you might mean "Begin your journey to wellness", but can't be sure.

*Set* does not have this meaning, but the idiom "set out on" is used specifically for journeys, so "Set out on your journey to wellness" works, though it focuses a bit more on the idea of a literal journey than a figurative one. I'd therefore advise against unless perhaps it was used with some visual imagery of journeys that would more strongly bring the imagery to mind. (Metaphors need to either be strong in the imagery or else quiet and let the figurative meaning dominate, "set out on" risks falling between the two).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jon.. "set out on" how it would mean with the sentence?

Comment: "Set out on" is an idiom that means "begin" specifically in terms of journeys, adventures and similar.